# No module named 'super_gradients'?

Tags: module, yolo

I tried to install "super_gradients" on colab using !pip install super-gradients==3.1.0
and when i import packages
import "super_gradients"
from super_gradients.training import Trainer, dataloaders, models
I get error  No module named 'super_gradients'
I tried to restart run time and it worked about a month ago, but today it is not

I tried to restart run time and it worked about a month ago, but today it is not, so I expect to import packages successfully.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like this version doesn't work. when I used `!pip install super-gradients`, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

yes the problem is with versioning error.
use !pip install super-gradients
directly